# How to source files in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am trying a simple means of sourcing a file based on the filetype of the new opened file. For example, I want to source python.vimrc when a new file is *.py. This code (in .vimrc)

```
function LoadFileTypeDefaults()
  let vimrcfile = &filetype . '.vimrc' 
  if filereadable(vimrcfile)
    echo vimrcfile
    source vimrcfile
  endif
endfunction
```

gives the following error when I do `vi new.py`

> python.vimrc
>
> Error detected while processing function LoadFileTypeDefault:
>
> line    4:
>
> E484: Can't open file vimrcfile

My python.vimrc is in my runpath. Moreover, if I replace

```
source vimrcfile
```

with

```
source python.vimrc
```

everything works as required.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `source` command expects a file name, not an expression. You gave it `vimrcfile` so it’s looking for the file called `vimrcfile`. Use `execute` to string together a command from one or more expressions.

```
exe 'source' vimrcfile
```

(If you pass multiple arguments they will be joined with spaces before executing.)

---

What you probably really want is to just add

```
autocmd Filetype python set expandtab " etc
```

in your `.vimrc`.

---

Or if you really have a lot of settings, put them in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `execute "source " . vimrcfile`?

Comment: `execute "source ".fnameescape(vimrcfile)`

Answer (score 2):

Vim has a system for dealing with this kind of thing, called filetype plugins, or ftplugins.

In your `~/.vim` (or whatever is standard on your OS), go to the `ftplugins` directory (create if it doesn't exist) and create a `python` directory under that. Any `.vim` file under that directory will automatically be sourced when a `.py` file is loaded.

Note that you need to have `filetype plugin on`.

Alternatively you can do this with autocommands, though it is a bit cumbersome:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py source python.vimrc
```

Put that in your normal vimrc, and it'll do what you want.

Comment: Vim has `FileType` event for this kind of actions, so do not use `BufNewFile,BufRead`.

Comment: why can't you just write `source whatever.vim` since if you write `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` that works without error using this sytnax

Answer (score 0):

As a vim command:

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: That's not what OP requested: OP wants to source a file whose filename is stored in a variable. Also OP was actually looking for filetype plugins (or event which I won't recommend): vimrc configuration is loaded once per vim session while filetype specific configuration needs to be loaded once per buffer of the related filetype.